# Async/Await and Task<T> does not return data

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-t

When I do this it doesn't return  `Task<TokenModel>` I mean this line is freezing `tokenModel = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TokenModel>();`

```
Foo()
{
   var r = IsLoginOk();
}
public async Task<TokenModel> IsLoginOk()
{

  var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
  handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
  handler.PreAuthenticate = true;
  handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;

  client = new HttpClient(handler);
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.WebApiUrl);
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));                

  var apiAccountLogin = apiManager.ApiAccountLogin(Properties.Settings.Default.WebApiPassword, Properties.Settings.Default.WebApiUsername);

  var response = await  client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiAccountLogin.Url, apiAccountLogin.Container);

  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();  
  tokenModel = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TokenModel>();

  return tokenModel;
}
```

But if I use `void` then it is working fine

```
Foo()
{
     IsLoginOk();
}
public async void IsLoginOk()
{

  var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
  handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
  handler.PreAuthenticate = true;
  handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;

  client = new HttpClient(handler);
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.WebApiUrl);
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));                

  var apiAccountLogin = apiManager.ApiAccountLogin(Properties.Settings.Default.WebApiPassword, Properties.Settings.Default.WebApiUsername);

  var response = await  client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiAccountLogin.Url, apiAccountLogin.Container);

  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();  
  tokenModel = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TokenModel>();   
}
```

As I see my code is like Microsift example code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx .

Is this kind of  some **Deadlock**?

I need to return **tokenModel**. How I can do this?
Thanks!

Comment: So it's not even returning a task? have you tried seeing is the IsLoginOk().Result; available? If it returns a task, if you check it's state and see if it is state "RanToCompletion".

Comment: Avoid async void methods. See http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/

Comment: As long as i remember,  async void is like Fire-And-Forget async task, that's why it work for you. And when you await and return await Task you get a deadlock or just a long-running operation, which blocks your main thread.

Comment: Generally it is a bad idea to call an async method from a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but your code should be like this

1. This is one way to do it

   ```
   public async void Foo()
   {
     var r = await IsLoginOk();
   }
   ```
2. Way to do it make use of `ConfigureAwait(false)` like as below when making call.

   ```
   var jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
   ```

---

For this behaviour I searched on Google and found this good article. Please read it to avoid future problems: [**Don't Block on Async Code**](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

### **Reason of deadlock**

if code is like this

```
public static async Task<JObject> GetJsonAsync(Uri uri)
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    var jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    return JObject.Parse(jsonString);
  }
}

// My "top-level" method.
public void Button1_Click(...)
{
  var jsonTask = GetJsonAsync(...);
  textBox1.Text = jsonTask.Result;
}
```

that it hangs So this is what happens, starting with the top-level method (Button1_Click for UI):

1. The top-level method calls GetJsonAsync (within the UI context).
2. GetJsonAsync starts the REST request by calling HttpClient.GetStringAsync (still within the context).
3. GetStringAsync returns an uncompleted Task, indicating the REST request is not complete.
4. GetJsonAsync awaits the Task returned by GetStringAsync. The context is captured and will be used to continue running the GetJsonAsync method later. GetJsonAsync returns an uncompleted Task, indicating that the GetJsonAsync method is not complete.
5. The top-level method synchronously blocks on the Task returned by GetJsonAsync. This blocks the context thread.
6. … Eventually, the REST request will complete. This completes the Task that was returned by GetStringAsync.
7. The continuation for GetJsonAsync is now ready to run, and it waits for the context to be available so it can execute in the context.
8. Deadlock. The top-level method is blocking the context thread, waiting for GetJsonAsync to complete, and GetJsonAsync is waiting for the context to be free so it can complete.

Comment: @ClarkKent - check link of my answer it will clear what is problem

Comment: if my solution accepted and working why there is - 1?

Comment: I guess it was someone else but not me my friend. Your solution is great! I am sure you can ask your friends to vote... ;) And special THANK YOU for the link.

Comment: @ClarkKent - welcome...its not about vote it just about what is reason...because votes are just for those who want to show rep but I just do it for learning and keep my self updated

Answer (score 3):

Change your constructor like this:

```
private Foo()
{
    // Do only synchronous initialization here
}

public static async Task<Foo> CreateAsync()
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    await foo.IsLoginOk();
    return foo;
}
```

Your callside needs to be changed accordingly.

Comment: Oh, sorry I was assuming Foo() is a constructor. Now I see that it's rather a private method.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is [causing a deadlock that I explain on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). In short, when `await` pauses an `async` method, by default it will capture a context (e.g., a UI context or ASP.NET request context). Later, when the `await` completes, the `async` method is resumed in that context. However, if the calling code uses `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result` to synchronously block on the `async` method, then it is blocking a thread within that context and the `async` method cannot complete.

The *proper* solution is to use `async` all the way, not use `async void` or `ConfigureAwait(false)`:

```
async Task FooAsync()
{
  var result = await IsLoginOkAsync();
}

public async Task<TokenModel> IsLoginOkAsync();
```

Answer (score -1):

IsLoginOk() will return a Task.
To return a TokenModel alone, use

```
var r = IsLoginOk().Result;
```

If you don't wait for the result, execution will continue, as it is async. Also, Name should be IsLoginAsync()

Comment: .Result might cause deadlock?